# How can I make codepipeline to build every branch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration

I am using codebuild and codepipeline for CI/CD. I have a source stage in codepipeline to load the source code from bitbucket. However, I have to specify a branch name for my repo. Is there a way for me to let it build every branch? I tried to put `*` in the branch name field but it doesn't allow me to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in one source action.

But you can have **multiple source actions** in the first stage of your pipeline. Thus you could create one source action, in parallel, for each branch in the source stage.

Then in the second stage, you could one CodeBuild action which takes from [1 to 5 input artifices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-input).  Similarly you can have up to [5 outputs actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-output) from a CodeBuild.

Thus, depending on how many brunches you have, you may need to have more than one CodeBuild.

Comment: Do I have to manually update the source actions when there is a new branch get created? In many other CI tools, it build new branch without changing any configuration. Can I do that in codepipeline?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I'm not aware of how you could dynamically add actions to codepipline in an "easy" way.

Comment: Thanks @Marchin, that's a shame since building different branches is very common requirement for CI. Most of my teams are using feature branch and there will be many branches get created.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao No problem. May try with Jenkins. It has good integration with AWS through its plugins.